# Searching for k elements in array of size n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Let say that I got a sorted array of size n , and m is the maximal number in the array - therefore the most right number in the array.
So I want to check if all the elements from m to m/n for example are in the array.
can I do it in O(n)? all I can think about is O(n^2) when trying to locate the sub array and search there for each element.

Thanks!

Comment: if the array is sorted you can do a binary search which is O(log n) if you do it for k elements it will be   O (k log (n))

Comment: is it log(n) if i have k searches while k may be = O(n)

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: Consider that my array is sorted, i want to check if it contains a set of elements between m to n/m - can i do it in just log(n) ?

Comment: Your question says you're looking for all items between m and m/n. But your comment says n/m. Which is it?

Comment: m to m/n , sorry for confusing.

Comment: Why do you say you need to locate a subarray? Are the elements of the array integer?

Comment: No , Im looking for solution also for decimal numbers.

Comment: Explain better the part of the subarray. What have you tried?

Comment: Let me make it clear -1.  Im looking for the both cases that the numbers in the array may be also decimal or integers(both solutions may be very helpfull) , thats first. 2.the part of the subarray is just one solution I tried to develop , therefore it is not critical part of the question. 3. The button line is can i verify that my sorted array has all the numbers between m to m/n in O(n) and how?

Comment: You can't if the array has decimals. There are infinite numbers inbetween let's say the range is [0,5] you'll need to check if 0.01, 0.02, etc are present in the array or at least, that's what I understand from your statements. If the array has only integers, yes you can do it in linear time.

Comment: OK, and if i have a finite number of decimal numbers? let say in in range [0,5] i have to check if {1.1 , 1.5 , 2  , ..... ,  5}.

Comment: What do you mean by "the most right number in the array" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the last number in the sorted array, e.g, the max.

Comment: And what do you mean by "all the elements from m to m/n for example" ?

Comment: let say that I have a set of number in range of [m , m/n] - with a finite number of elements which may be decimal numbers.

Comment: @BarakMi Best time would be *klog(n)* where *k* is the  size of the subarray you need to search

Comment: Is still can't get it. m/n is smaller than m, why do you invert the range ?

Comment: My bad! its [m/n , m].

Comment: If you can use extra memory you can do it in o(n+k)

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra consider that k = O(n) so i get that the complexity is O(n). can u please explain how you check each element if it is in the array?

Comment: Also, a range like [m/n, m] is infinite, I don't think this is a good example.

Comment: Well, it seems yvis gave you the answer first than me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, creat a new bit array of the size m-m/n (rounded) then start from the right of your old array and read the number, make that number a suitable index for your new array to set it to true. once you finish passing through your old array make an "And" between all bits of the new array, if the result is true then you have all required numbers, otherwise you don't have all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array from the last position (max value) to the first one (min value) and start checking for `M` value, if the number appears, then continue checking for `M - 1`, then `M - 2` and so on.

You don't need to worry about any number less than the current you're checking since the array is sorted.

If at any time you found a number in the array less than the current checking number you can stop since all the remaining numbers will be lowers.

If at the end your current number is less than `M/N` you can say that range `[M/N - M]` is in the array.

This is some kind of pseudo-code, for simplicity I'm looking for numbers between `MIN` and `MAX` (You just need to change `MAX` by `M` and `MIN` by `M/N`):

```
MAX: Int, MIN: Int, ARR: Int[]

K: Int = MAX

For I = Length(ARR) DOWN-TO 1
    If ARR[I] == K Then K = K - 1
    Else If (ARR[I] < K) Then Return (FALSE)

Return (K <= MIN)
```

As you can see this is `O(N)` since each element in `ARR` is visited once.

Answer (score 0):

For small k, lookup all test values by dichotomic search, for a total of k Log(n) comparisons.

For larger k, sort the k test values increasingly and compare the two sorted lists. This will take O(k Log(k) + min(k, n)) comparisons.

You can also insert all test values in a hash table, and lookup all input values in the hash table; this takes roughly O(k + n) operations.